# About jquery.off and the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using  bootstrap-dropdown to generate a Dropdown menu.
I would like to disable some default behaviour by using jQuery.off.

1) how can I disable the disappear of Dropdown menu on a specific element and not all elements?
2) how can I disable the appearing of menu on a specific element and not all elements?

By using the following code I reach my goal by I would like to apply this behaviour on a specific element and not on all the document.

```
$('html').off('click.dropdown'); // it disable the disappear of Dropdown menu.
$('body').off('click.dropdown'); // it disable  the appearing of Dropdown menu. 
// Why this differance?
```

.​​​​

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVaqX/2) link to test the code. 
Thanks to @merv for making the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use the `off()` method to disable a binding on a specific element that already has a binding.  In pointing out `$('html').off()`, I was merely trying to demonstrate that the only binding which auto-closes dropdown menus is attached there.

Otherwise, you can add a new binding to elements in dropdown menus to stop the click event from bubbling up to the `html` element:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click.dropdown', function(e) {e.stopPropagation()})​​​​​
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVaqX/7/)

Comment: let's suppose I have another event on "click.dropdown" how should I handle it?

Comment: The reason why I'm asking you to chat is that I don't think it is appropriate to append additional questions to the comments which go outside the scope of the initial question.  I would be happy to answer your question there: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14704/discussion-on-on-off

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".disabled-link").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});​
```

add the "disabled-link" class to any dropdown you don't want to work

Comment: what about that ^^ changed my answer

Comment: Actually my goal is to avoid to use event.preventDefault or event.stopPropagation .. for this reason the question is about jQuery.off